# How to use reducers in nested components?

Tags: asp.net-core, react-redux

I have a react.component - FetchData. It has connection to action-reducer-store. In action-reducer-store it fetches data from api and render result in FetchData component.

```js
export class FetchData extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props.requestWeatherForecasts(0);
    }

  render() {
    return ...;
  }
}

export default connect(
  state => state.weatherForecasts,
  dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
)(FetchData);
```

It works perfectly fine if I go direct to component using route:

```html
<Route path='/fetch-data/' component={FetchData}>
```

The problem occurs if I move FetchData to another component, like Home:

```js
const Home = props => (<FetchData />)
```

So I go to component Home with route:

```html
<Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
```

and expect to see FetchData inside Home component but get errors instead like there are no connected action-reducer-store in FetchData at all

My step by step actions:

I created an asp.net core react.js + redux empty application.
Then I changed FetchData.js class to export class.

```js
export class FetchData extends Component
```

Then I imported FetchData and replaced body in Home.js.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { FetchData } from './FetchData';

const Home = props => (
    <FetchData />
);

export default connect()(Home);
```

On that moment reducer stops working in FetchData.js (or at least it seems like so)

- I have tried to make Home.js a React.Component class.
- I have tried to add constructor with super(props) in FetchData.js.
- I have tried to add default connect from FetchData to Home.

Comment: Did you remember to mapDispatchtoProps and mapStatetoProps?

Comment: Can you post the whole file's code?

Comment: You need connect with FetchData so make sure it is ```export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FetchData)``` at the bottom of the file.

Comment: @Mark, I have posted it on git - https://github.com/Demonell/ReduxApp
FetchData.js has at buttom:
    export default connect(
        state => state.weatherForecasts,
        dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
    )(FetchData);
 - and it works fine when it's not nested

Comment: Change ```export default connect()(Home);``` to just ```export default Home```.  There is no need to use ```connect``` here.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?  I'm kind of confused.

Comment: @Mark, I have updated my question to made it more clear.

Comment: Have you tried throwing console logs in your action creators to see if it's hitting them?

Comment: I added an answer.  Did that work for you?

Comment: @Mark, Yes, thank you very much! Solution was so simple >,<

Comment: No problem... I've definitely made that mistake before =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing your component incorrectly

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import FetchData from './FetchData';

const Home = props => (
    <FetchData />
);

export default connect()(Home);
```

Remove the brackets around `FetchData` the brackets are used for non default exports from a file.  In your case that is `./FetchData`. Since you used `export default` you do not need the brackets.